# Visual Studio Code Analysis with ramdisk?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis, ramdisk

I used SoftPerfect RAM Disk recently to boost up my build time. It is awesome the normal build time has shrinked from 3 minutes to about 30 seconds for my whole solution, however I noticed that Code Analysis stopped working for me.

I have pointed all of my Debug folders under bin and obj folders of each project to a ramdisk symlink folder. The command I used is:

```
mklink /d "c:\myprojectbase\someproject\bin\Debug" "R:\ramdisk\Debug"
```

I normally open run Code Analysis manually through the Code Analysis tab and select the project which I want to run the code analysis against. It now gives me error:

```
Metadata file 'c:\myprojectbase\someproject\bin\Debug\DependencyLib.dll' could not be found
```

Seems the compiler deletes all dependency libraries the project relies on, but couldn't rebuild them correctly into the symlink folder. If I delete the symlink, all those libraries then got generated
correctly. Interestingly, if I check the "Enable Code Analysis on Build" in the project properties and then build the project, the Code Analysis also works.

Has anyone seen this issue or have any workaround?

Comment: `RAM Disk` - Jeez, buy a freaking SSD.

Comment: Not exactly appropriate giving that an SSD Is still - hm - 100 times slower ;) I Wish I could get a RAM based disc outside of CRAZY prices (15000€ for 32 or something) for my database servers.

Comment: @TomTom agree. I am already on an SSD, but it is just not fast enough for building big projects. That's why I started to use RamDisk.